# Compiling issues : Apache headers not found - CentOS 6.x

Tags: apache, apache-portable-runtime

I am trying to build libwurfl (https://github.com/filosganga/libwurfl) on CentOS. I have installed all the dependent libraries, but I am having issues with running configure for libwurfl. I am constantly getting issues with Apache headers not found issue.

If I use --with-apxs as shown below,

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs/
```

Output:

```
checking for apr.h... yes
checking httpd.h usability... no
checking httpd.h presence... no
checking for httpd.h... no
configure: error: Apache headers not found.
```

If I add --with-apache

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs/ --with-apache=/usr/include/httpd/
```

Output:

```
checking for apxs... no
checking apr.h usability... no
checking apr.h presence... no
checking for apr.h... no
configure: error: Apache Portable Runtime headers not found.
```

I see headers on both locations mentioned above.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I compiled it on Ubuntu 14.04 after installing and configuring apr-1.5.2 and httpd 2.2.31. Then I compiled it in this way:`./configure --with-apache='/usr/local/apache2'`